# alternating panel animations inside a loop

Tags: basic4android

I have two panels animating (blinking on/off) fine as heartbeats. However I want them to alternate beating instead of at the same time. So panel1 beats with a 10 count and then panel2 beats with a 10 count. I then want this to loop so it continues the pattern until the user presses the back key to exit the activity. I tried a few things with no luck. Here is the two panels beating together...

```
Sub beats
    PNL1.Initialize("PNL1")
    gdpanel1.Initialize("TOP_BOTTOM", Array As Int(Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Red))
    gdpanel1.CornerRadius=0
    PNL1.Background=gdpanel1
    mainPNL.AddView(PNL1,0,0,100%x,50%y)
    SetRadialGradientRed(gdpanel1,PNL1.Height/1.5)
    a.InitializeAlpha("a",0,1)
    a.Duration = 200
    a.RepeatCount = 10
    a.Start(PNL1)
    PNL2.Initialize("PNL1")
    gdpanel2.Initialize("TOP_BOTTOM", Array As Int(Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Blue))
    gdpanel2.CornerRadius=0
    PNL2.Background=gdpanel2
    mainPNL.AddView(PNL2,0,50%y,100%x,50%y)
    SetRadialGradientBlue(gdpanel2,PNL2.Height/1.5)
    b.InitializeAlpha("b",0,1)
    b.Duration = 200
    b.RepeatCount = 10
    b.Start(PNL2)
End Sub

Sub a_AnimationEnd
    '
End Sub

Sub b_AnimationEnd
    '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start animation b in Sub a_AnimationEnd and start animation a in Sub b_AnimationEnd.